# AVI Compression - CBR not configurable

Tags: c#, directshow, encoder, bitrate

I wrote a C# code that captures video from a video capture card, and writes it in a AVI file. I'm using the XviD encoder (DirectShow).
I'm using the IAMVfwCompressDialogs interface to get the configuration form open, and I am also trying to configure it going to the same form in the start menu.
I need to record 30 minutes of video, without audio, and I need this file to be 2Mb big.
I set the Target bitrate property of the Video Encoder of the Xvid to 10 (kbps), and the Target Quantizer property to 16.
The file size did not changed.
Then I tryed to modify those two property to many different combinations, but I get no change.
My problem is: I changing the XviD configurations to change the file size, modifing the bitrate and the quality properties, but the result is aways the same.
Is there any way I can set 30 minutes video file size to be around 2Mb big, even by modifing the bitrate or quality, with 1 fps, 240x192 framesize, very low video quality? Is there any problems with XviD filter when using it on a C# service? Is there any other good filter to use with DirectShow on c# applications?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are off by several orders of magnitude.  Unless you record a video of 16 x 16 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how... It may sound weird, but when I set the windows service to inicialize with the same user that installed the Xvid codecs, it works fine.